# Encode probability distribution in single cell of table

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

Is there any mechanism for storing all the information of a probability distribution (discrete and/or continuous) into a **single cell** of a table? If so, how is this achieved and how might one go about making queries on these cells?

Comment: Why do you need a single cell, exactly? Storing multiple values in a single cell is a bad idea, since it's going against the most basic 1st normal form, rendering many SQL operation useless and making queries much more weird and difficult. Also, please elaborate further on "all the information about probability distribution", what info that includes? Multiple pairs of (value,probability) or something more, or something else entirely?

Comment: Its not that I need a single cell, I was just hoping to minimize storage. As there are several families of distributions, I suppose they would require as much information as necessary. As arkascha mentioned below, I am quite happy to know that a reference to a distribution can be stored and there are ways of querying such objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very vague. So only general hints can be provided.

I'd say there are two typical approaches for this (*if* I got your question right):

1. you *can* store some complex data into a single "cell" (how you call it) inside a database table. Easiest for this is to use `JSON` encoding. So you have an array of values, encode that to a string and store that string. If you want to access the values again you query the string and decode it back into an array. Newer versions of MariaDB or MySQL offer an extension to access such values on sql level too, though access is pretty slow that way.
2. you use an additional table for the values and store only a reference in the cell. This actually is the typical and preferred approach. This is how the relational database model works. The advantage of this approach is that you can directly access each value separately in sql, that you can use mathematical operations like sums, averages and the like on sql level and that you are not limited in the amount of storage space like you are when using a single cell. Also you can filter the values, for example by date ranges or value boundaries.

In the end, taking all together, both approaches offer the same, though they require different handling of the data. The fist approach additionally requires some scripting language on the client side to handle encoding and decoding, but that typically is given anyway.

The second approach us considered cleaner and will be faster in most of the cases, except if you always access to whole set of values at all times. So a decision can only be made when knowing more specific details about the environment and goal of an implementation.

Comment: Thanks for such valuable general hints. Is the second approach preferred because its easier to code and/or understand? I've found the JSON data structures to be somewhat ugly due to the fact that they are just deeply nested dictionaries.

Comment: I added some general notes. But it cannot be stressed enough that these are very general considerations. You would have to post more specific details about what it is you are trying to do for us to offer more specific help. About JSON being "ugly"... Look at it this way: statistical data is easiest stored in some sort of dictionary or array. How else would you do that? And if you have a dictionary or array, then what is "ugly" in using such structure to store the data? Obviously other formats do exist, but they offer no real alternative, only different coding. `JSON` is the de facto standard.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a distribution in column **B** like:

[image]

and we want to place the distribution in a **single** cell.  In **C1** enter:

=B1

and in **C2** enter:

```
=B1 & CHAR(10) & C1
```

and copy downwards.  Finally, format cell **C13** with wrap on:

[image]